# Moving Wordpress from Server to Local

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache

I'm trying to move a Wordpress website from a server to my local machine.
After I've transferred the files and database, I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: require_once(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/karryon/wp-config.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/karryon/wp-load.php on line 29

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/karryon/wp-config.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/karryon/wp-load.php on line 29
```

I'm using XAMPP on a mac and I've tried changing the folder permissions with no luck.

Strange thing is I tried doing the same on a windows machine with Wampserver using the exact same steps and it worked fine.

If anyone knows a possible solution to this problem please let me know!

Thanks in advance,

Amy

Comment: What are the file permissions and ownership settings?

Comment: It's set to "Read & Write" for wp-config.php

Comment: Try recursively setting your local permissions to 777. It will fire up. From there, tune it so that it's using 755 permissions.